# jQuery Mobile Buttons not appended properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button

I am trying to append buttons to a header if a case is true, but it ends up looking like this:
[image]

The edit and new event buttons are supposed to be a control group...

HTML

```
<div data-role="header">
<h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" id="hdr"></h1>
<div class="ui-btn-right" id ="addbuttons" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#addbuttons').append('<div data-role="button" data-icon="gears" data-theme="b">Edit</div>');
$('#addbuttons').append('<div data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">New Event</div>');
```

Comment: What does this do with PHP and MySQL? Seriously?

Comment: mb, i had a different question before, then i changed it, forgot to change the tags; sorry man why did u vote me down

Comment: This is not a duplicate @RachelGallen :) different approach, difference code. Pls compare both answers, mine and in the link you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you do any changes to header or footer, you need to re-enhance the markup this way.

```
$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
```

You also can use this,

```
$('[data-role=header]').trigger('create');
```

Comment: i dont need to create a page though? and after where do i put the append

Comment: After you append the items.